# how to can get the value of callback function out side callback function in express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, callback

```
app.get('/allColleges', (req, res) => {

 collegeModel.find().sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 }).exec((err, colleges) => {
        if (!colleges || colleges.length === 0) {
          return res.status(200).json(null)
        } else {
          var collegedata = Array.from(colleges)
 
          for (i = 0; i < collegedata.length; i++) {
            var collegeGalleryData = {};
            var collegeGallery = collegeGalleryModel.find({collegeId: collegedata[i]._id}, (err, collegeGallery) => {
                if (!collegeGallery || collegeGallery.length > 0){
                    collegeGalleryData.data = collegeGallery;
                } 
            })
            collegedata[i].collegeGallery = collegeGalleryData.data;
          }
            
         }

  return res.json(collegedata)
 })

})
```

I've created an API in Express JS. In this API I need data from a collection outside the callback function to which the result of the query is passed.
I created an object variable and add a key "data" in callback function and try to set its value to the data found in the second query with `collegeGalleryModel`.
When I check the value of `data` in this object *outside* the callback function, it is empty.
So, how can we get the result value passed to a callback function *outside* the callback function?

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: Try using the async/await api on the queries rather than callbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that you *can't* get the value passed to a callback function outside of it in this scenario, because of how [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in javascript work.

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but it seems that, for each object in the `collegedata` array, you want to run some query and store the result in a `collegeGallery` key in the object.

You could easily use [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) for this.

Here's how I refactored it:

```
app.get('/allColleges', (req, res) => {

  (async() => {

    try{
       const colleges = await collegeModel.find().sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 }).exec();
              let collegedata = null;
              
                if(colleges.length>0){
                  collegedata = Array.from(colleges);
       
                  for (const dataObj of collegedata) {

                      const collegeGallery = await collegeGalleryModel.find({collegeId: dataObj._id})
                      dataObj.collegeGallery = collegeGallery;
                   }

                }

        res.json(collegedata);

    } catch(e) {
      console.error(`ERROR: ${e.message}`);

      res.status(500).send({
        message: e.message || "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
      })
    }
     

  })();

})
```

Some observations about your code, though:

1. You seem to have done no error handling, I've done some for you; you can modify according to your requirements.
2. Based on your code, in the case that the first query returns no objects, you're responding with `null`. I haven't seen that anywhere, I'm not sure express will allow you to do that. However, my refactored code will also respond with `null`, although I would prefer to either return an empty array or a 404 response.

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer if it worked for you :)